# Session timeout if no activity in 15 minutes not working?

Tags: yii2

I use advanced template and I can successfully session timeout in 15 minutes but it doesn't depends on activity, so even user active in website after login he will be logout after 15 minutes.

I know the idea I should put trigger to increase timeout in SiteController, but don't know how to implement it.

So far here is my code

`backend\config\main.php`

```
  'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'authTimeout' => 900
        ],
        'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'cookieparams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 900],
            'timeout' => 900,
            'useCookies' => true,
        ],
```

`frontend\config\main.php`

```
'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\UserCustomer',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            //'enableSession' => true,
              'authTimeout' => 900,
        ],
        'session' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Session',
            'cookieparams' => ['httponly' => true, 'lifetime' => 900],
            'timeout' => 900,
            'useCookies' => true,
        ],
```

What should I do now? so I can implement session timeout if no activity in 15 minutes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is different and there is a better solution than putting a trigger in your controller.
Most probably you are not setting a duration for http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#login()-detail. Search for the line where you login the user. Probably something like:

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser());
```

change to

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), 900);
```

There are also several reasons this might not be working, but this is the most obvious.

Comment: already implement trigger on every controller, maybe your solution is for next update. thanks alot anyway.